# Converting list of Map<String, Object> to Map<String,String>

Tags: java, list, collections, java-8

I have a list of map.

```
Map<String, Object> steps1 = new HashMap<>();
steps1.put("key11", "value11");
steps1.put("key12", "value12");
steps1.put("key21","hye");

Map<String, Object> steps2 = new HashMap<>();
steps2.put("key21", "value21");
steps2.put("key22", "value22");
steps2.put("key11","hello");

List<Map<String, Object>> steps = new ArrayList<>();
steps.add(steps1);
steps.add(steps2);
```

And a list of keys.

```
List<String> oldKeys = Arrays.asList("key21","key11");
```

I want to convert the list of map to `Map<String,String>`, where the values would be comma separated values.

The final result would be :

`[key11="value11,hello", key21="hye,value21"]`

I can do it by looping and a bit verbose code but want to do it using Java 8 style.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to stream both entry sets, then flatten them to one stream and group by key mapping values to proper string (meanwhile you can filter by your keys)

```
Stream.of(steps1.entrySet(), steps2.entrySet())
            .flatMap(Set::stream)
            .filter(e -> oldKeys.contains(e.getKey()))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(v -> String.valueOf(v.getValue()), Collectors.joining(","))));
```

However I'm always a big fan of writing readable code not fancy one. The example above is quite clear but if it would be too hard to understand you should definitely forgot about "Java 8 style" and write simple loop

Answer (score 0):

Same approach as m.antkowitz but just treating the input as a list of maps as mentioned in the question:

```
var result = steps.stream()
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(entry -> oldKeys.contains(entry.getKey())))
            .collect(toList()).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(e -> e.getValue().toString(),
                            Collectors.joining(","))));
```

As mentioned, it is a case where streams may not be ideal. Static imports would tidy this up a bit, but even so, it is not a piece of code that I would want to return to and try to understand later on.

Not being facetious, but another option is to use Kotlin, which has a richer set of collection functions particularly around grouping and aggregating. I haven't repeated the exercise in Kotlin but my gut feeling is that something far more readable would be possible.